# Rails: How do I associate a submit_tag to a search_field_tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following code in my view:

```
<% form_tag(search_path) %>
<%= search_field_tag("search", nil, placeholder: "Book name") %>
<%= submit_tag ("Search") %>
```

And the following route:

```
search_path POST    /search(.:format)   searches#create
```

The form appears correctly but when I click submit nothing happens. Server logs show absolutely nothing. Chrome Dev tools shows nothing happens on the client side. I think that the way I am constructing this form is incorrect. I think I need to add something to associates the different tags I have, and without this element all these form elements are all disassociated and fragmented. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `do` to the end of your `form_tag`. This is how Rails associates the different elements of the form.

```
<%= form_tag(search_path) do %>
<%= search_field_tag("search", nil, placeholder: "Book name") %>
<%= submit_tag ("Search") %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

"Doing-Ending" the form_tag is a good practice, but I'd say your only problem is the lack of the = sign in the embedded Ruby syntax.